# Monitoring AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-data-pipeline

In our infrastructure we have a bunch of pipelines for ETL data before pushing them into Redshift. We use s3 bucket for logs and SNS alerting for activities. Most of that activities are standard CopyActivity, RedshiftCopyActivity and SqlActivity.
We want to get all available metrics for this activities to dashboard them (E.g.: Cloudwatch) so we know what's going on that side in one single place. Unfortunately I didn't find much information on AWS documentation for that and have to do all that manually in code.

What is the most common way for monitoring AWS Data Pipeline?

Comment: Cloudwatch shows you metrics from the instances where your activities is running. It is not very convenient, but you can find a specific instance where the pipeline was running, and if you have a pipeline failure or performance issue correlate that metrics to the problem.

Let me know if you find a better way.

Comment: Thanks @enisher for suggestion. Performance Monitoring on EC2 instance that Data Pipeline creates could be easily added, however it doesn't bring specific activities metrics. For simple steps of RDS => S3 => Redshift I'm planning to add a Lambda that will be monitoring new objects on S3 and emit Cloudwatch metrics for amount of bytes processed, also I'll add Redshift write bytes operation into Cloudwatch dashboard. If I find anything more generic, I will comment here.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution?